# How do I save information for a user of a website?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code (on a website): https://stick-z.github.io/
Alternatively, here is the HTML, and JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Poster</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>To-Do:</h1>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>This is</li>
    <li>A test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="input">
    <input id="form" type="text"></input>
    <button id="enter">Add</button>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const list = document.getElementById("list")
const enter = document.getElementById("enter")

enter.addEventListener("click", add => {
    var input = document.getElementById("form").value
    var node = document.createElement("LI")
    var text = document.createTextNode(input)
    node.appendChild(text)
    list.appendChild(node)
})
document.querySelector('#list').addEventListener('click', function({target}) {
  if (target.matches('li'))
    target.remove()
}, false);
```

I want to be able to reload the page, and have my "To-Do's" that I made before remain there.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code utilises [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the list contents and load it when the website reloads.

I have added `localStorage.setItem('items', document.getElementById("list").innerHTML);` to the end of each event listener to update the list and have added `list.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("items");` at the end of the JavaScript file to load the saved list when the webpage is loaded.

**I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/zs6L87kw/) with the working code.**

---

### Side Note

*You did not put a semi-colon (`;`) after each line in the JavaScript file, which is bad practice, and you put a closing tag on the HTML `<input>` element when input elements do not have closing tags.*

---

## Code

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Poster</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To-Do:</h1>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>This is</li>
    <li>A test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="input">
    <input id="form" type="text">
    <button id="enter">Add</button>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### JavaScript

```js
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const enter = document.getElementById("enter");

enter.addEventListener("click", add => {
    var input = document.getElementById("form").value;
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var text = document.createTextNode(input);
    node.appendChild(text);
    list.appendChild(node);
    localStorage.setItem('items', document.getElementById("list").innerHTML);
})
document.querySelector('#list').addEventListener('click', function({target}) {
  if (target.matches('li'));
    target.remove();
    localStorage.setItem('items', document.getElementById("list").innerHTML);
}, false);

list.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("items");
```

Comment: When I use this on my (github hosted) website, my information is still not saved after reload. https://stick-z.github.io/ for refrence

Comment: It works for me. Try clearing your cache. `Ctrl+Shift+Delete`.